# Logging within a package

Tags: python, logging

I'm developing a package that will be used by others to write processing scripts. For testing/debugging/not-going-insane purposes, I'd like to include some logging statements within my code, and especially using a `logging_setup()` utility function that I developed for another project for formatting/file output control.

Because I'm not writing a self-contained application, however, but a library that is meant to be called by other programs, I am confused where I should use my `logging_setup()` utility in order to produce the desired logging results that I want. This made me wonder whether using a logging system within my package was a good idea to begin with.

Where should I use my `logging_setup()` utility, if anywhere?

EDIT: Here's the function I mention above:

```
def logging_setup(cfg_path=definitions.LOG_CONFIG_PATH, lvl=logging.INFO):
    """Setup logging tool from YAML configuration file.

    This should only be run once. Formatted (or configured) logging can only be
    done from within functions/classes in other modules.
    """

    # create directory for log files if not already there
    try:
        os.makedirs(definitions.LOGS_PATH)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

    # configure logging from yaml config file
    if os.path.exists(cfg_path):
        with open(cfg_path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())

        logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=lvl)
```

Comment: What exactly does `logging_setup()` do?

Comment: Unless you want to show a sample setup and explain the behavior you want, it's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @wim. Fair enough.

Comment: Make the user call your function if they want logging.

Comment: Okay- thank you. This was, as I was hoping it would be, a learning experience.

Comment: Libraries shouldn't be messing with the root logger; that's only for use by the top-level script.  Your package should have its own logger, created with `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, and any configuration you do should only be applied to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where should I use my `logging_setup()` utility, if anywhere?

In library code, you should not configure logging anywhere.  It is up to the users of your library (application distributors) to configure logging handlers.

As a library author, you don't know anything about the runtime context, you don't even know if there is a writable filesystem available at all in order to create logfiles. But to *use* `logging`, you don't need to care about the configuration - just `import logging` and create loggers, at the module level, and you can log events from library code. It is not for the library code to decide *where* those log events go - or if they go anywhere at all.

If you're providing an *app* and you want logging output, then configure logging as the first thing your application does when starting up - usually in Python this means a call to `logging.config.dictConfig` or similar is made shortly after entering the `main()` function (please make sure the logging configuration does not happen at `import` time).

Comment: For some support for this position, see the note under ["Configuring Logging for a Library" in the Logging HOWTO in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library).

Comment: In another project of mine (a self-contained application), I use this same function to spin up the proper logging configuration (for what I want to do). I was considering how I could have this same configuration here, but this answer is exactly what I was looking for: a description of good practice for writing libraries.

Much appreciated.